# Check on Array offset in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to check if an array offset exists or not ?

for example

```
$url = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

it returns

```
http://localhost/mediabox/home/box/12
```

when my header is clicked and I am on home page and returns

```
http://localhost/mediabox/home/box/12/en
```

when header is clicked and I am on some other page

```
How can I check if the url array contains that offset or not ?
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by "if the url array contains that offset"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isset()`, although I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

If under "offset" you mean "key", then use [array_key_exists](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

If you want to find a sbustring, use:

`strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "/en") !== false;`

Answer (score 0):

you can use function explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] ) , as delimiter use '/', and then check if end(array)=='en', or check if in_array('en',array), if it may be not at the end of the address